# add bootstrap element into body tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm a new bee in JQuery, I would like to use bootrap's spyscroll funcion in a specific page built by wordpress.

So My idea is to inject

```
data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20"
```

inside my page's body tag

which will be

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">
```

By using document.ready or onload function

```
$("body").append('data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20"');
```

I'm not sure if I can do it like this.

Thanks a lots

Comment: Just brief comment, since data-spy and data-target must to be placed into the body tag, so I couldn't do it on a simple div tag.

Comment: `var body = $('body');
body.attr({"data-spy":"scroll", "data-target":"#myScrollspy","data-offset":"20"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.data()` in jquery The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore free from memory leaks.

```
$("body").data("spy", "scroll");
$("body").data("target","#myScrollspy");
$("body").data("offset","20");
```

or alternate way

```
$.data( document.body, "spy", scroll);
$.data( document.body, "target", "#myScrollspy" );
$.data( document.body, "offset", "20" );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The append method is used to insert new HTML elements inside the parent, such as `<div>...</div>` and so on. To insert new attributes inside of the HTML element using jQuery you have tu use the `.attr()` method like that:

```
$( "body" ).attr( "data-spy", "scroll" );
$( "body" ).attr( "data-target", "#myScrollspy" );
$( "body" ).attr( "data-offset", "20" );
```

Hope it was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, it seems these code is working, no console bug, but in body tag, I still have nothing. it's because we use wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress surpasses the $ shortcut for jQuery, so you have to refer to jQuery more fully.

Answer (score 0):

I've added yours codes,but It's seems wordpress has some code mecanism makes this code not functional.

I finally found another solution by using this code:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#myScrollspy', offset:100 }
```

Maybe someone can tell me if wordpress denied inject element in body tag?